# power supply without original fan

Tags: power-supply, fan

Original fan (120 mm) rotates fast and makes quite a big noise

I replace original fan with 140 mm fan which makes little noise.

Original fan was located ~ 5 mm from other parts of power supply.

The replaced (140 mm) fan is located ~ 30 mm from other parts of power supply (the fan is located outside power supply box). Because replaced fan is bigger that original and there is no place inside the power supply box.

All works.

But I worry not to overheat power supply.

Is there any way to check (ensure) that power supply has normal temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of functioning in a fairly warm room touch the heatsink or, if not possible, the case of the PSU with the hand and see how hot it gets.

Normally it should be just fine as the main purpose of the fan is to remove warm air from the PSU.